# Redux: Is it possible to get info about changes in my subscription?

Tags: redux

Redux provides the `subscribe` function for the store changes notifying. But it doesn't contains detailed info about what changes was done... Is exist any way to subscribe only for changes are interesting for me and get detailed info about them (something like object which we pass into `dispatch` method)?

Comment: You could keep a reference to the old state, and then compare it when the new state comes in.  More importantly though is *why*. What are you trying to gain here?

Comment: I need to do changes logging.

Comment: If you just want to log the changes, you might want to check out [redux-logger](https://github.com/evgenyrodionov/redux-logger) - it will log the state before the action, then after the action, and there is an experimental option to print the diff.